# How do I create this simple graph working backwards?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I work in the SEO industry and I am trying to generate a graph for a client on how much traffic I think we can attract to his website over the next 6 months. The Y axis will be traffic volume, X axis will be months 1-6.

The only way I can really do this is by predicting how much traffic we will have in month 6 (since it will be too difficult to calculate before the site gets to page 1 of Google) and then working backwards.

Is there a formula I can put in Excel, for example, that, working backwards from month 6, would create a steady upwards progression until we get to that final traffic number?

Thank you very much in advance for any light you are able to shed on this.

Comment: This sounds like dynamic programming.

Comment: What's wrong with linear interpolation? And *how* do you predict the 6 moth value?

Comment: Thank you guys, but I'm not a maths expert so those terms don't mean all that much to me! I can predict the 6 month value based on other considerations (e.g. How much traffic can be attracted from appearing on page 1 of Google for a particular search term). I'm just looking for a formula to create a steady graph, months 1-6, leading up to that value... Thanks.